# Разъясните пож. как работают методы Redux Persist

Tags: redux

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist' \\что делают эти методы? Что они могут принимать и что возвращают?
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web \\ Этот storage что это такое? Какую функцию он выполняет?

import rootReducer from './reducers' \\ Это импорт редъюсера проекта? А если он не один? Или это что-то другое?

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
} \\ Для чего нужен этот обхект какова цель его создания?

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer) \\ Что мы тут получаем и для чего нам это нужно?

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
} \\ Куда это передаётся и как используется?
```